# How to list the nodes associated to a given vertex through intermediate nodes in TinkerPop3?

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a graph in TinkerPop3 in which the nodes are connected through edges with a given weight.

Given a node A in the graph I'm trying to traverse it to obtain all nodes which can be reached from A with less than N steps, and to sort them by a score. This score is calculated by mapping each edge in the path to that edge's weight divided by the step number and the total step, and finally summing the list.

Here is an example:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> a = g.addV('name','a').next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> b = g.addV('name','b').next()
==>v[2]
gremlin> c = g.addV('name','c').next()
==>v[4]
gremlin> d = g.addV('name','d').next()
==>v[6]
gremlin> e = g.addV('name','e').next()
==>v[8]
gremlin> a.addEdge('conn', b, 'weight', 1)
==>e[10][0-conn->2]
gremlin> a.addEdge('conn', c, 'weight', 3)
==>e[11][0-conn->4]
gremlin> b.addEdge('conn', d, 'weight', 3)
==>e[12][2-conn->6]
gremlin> d.addEdge('conn', e, 'weight', 9)
==>e[14][6-conn->8]
```

The expected scores for nodes related to "a" would be:

```
score_n = sum_over_n(weight_n-1n / (depth_n * total_N_from_a_to_n))
score_b = w_ab / (1 * 1) = 1 / 1 = 1
score_c = w_ac / (1 * 1) = 3 / 1 = 3
score_d = (w_ab / (1 * 2)) + (w_bd / (2 * 2)) = 1/2 + 3/4 = 5/4
score_e = (w_ab / (1 * 3)) + (w_bd / (2 * 3)) + (w_de / (3 * 3)) = 1/3 + 3/6 + 9/9 = 11/6
```

And thus, the result should be the corresponding nodes ordered decreasingly:

c e d b

I'm new to TinkerPop and Gremlin and I've been trying a combination of the repeat and sack steps without luck. The plan until now has been to accumulate the step in a sack for each traversal, to emit the score and node, and finally sort by score, but I'm worried about potential performance issues associated to the process.

Comment: Can you add the queries you tried but didn't work. It may be easier to start from where you are than from scratch.

Comment: Furthermore it would be beneficial if you could provide a sample graph and an expected result.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz I've added an example and expected result :)

Comment: @AlaaMahmoud My query is still far from working so it's not worth sharing. Even though I've added an example in the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the easiest traversal to start with TinkerPop. First thing I've changed is the data type for weights.

```
graph = TinkerGraph.open()
g = graph.traversal()
a = g.addV('name','a').next()
b = g.addV('name','b').next()
c = g.addV('name','c').next()
d = g.addV('name','d').next()
e = g.addV('name','e').next()
a.addEdge('conn', b, 'weight', 1f)
a.addEdge('conn', c, 'weight', 3f)
b.addEdge('conn', d, 'weight', 3f)
d.addEdge('conn', e, 'weight', 9f)
```

This was necessary to get rid of rounding errors. It could also be done as part of the traversal, but I didn't want to add even more steps as it already became complex enough:

```
gremlin> g.withSack(0).V().has("name","a").
           repeat(outE("conn").as("e").values("weight").as("w").
                  sack(assign).by(loops()).sack(sum).by(constant(1)).sack().as("l").
                  select("e").inV().as("v").select("v","w","l").as("x").select("v")).emit().
           select(all, "x").as("x").
           count(local).as("c").select("x").
           map(unfold().sack(assign).by(select("w")).
                        sack(div).by(select("l")).
                        sack(div).by(select("c")).sack().fold()).
           project("score","v").by(sum(local)).by(select("x").tail(local, 1).select("v")).
           order().by(select("score"), decr).select("v").values("name")
==>c
==>e
==>d
==>b
```

**UPDATE**

What follows is a working traversal for TP 3.0.1:

```
gremlin> Gremlin.version()
==>3.0.1-incubating
gremlin> g.withSack(0D).V().has("name","a").
           repeat(outE("conn").as("e").values("weight").as("w").
                  select(all,"w").count(local).as("l").
                  select(last,"e").inV().as("v").select(last,"v","w","l").as("x").select("v")).emit().
           select(all,"x").as("x").
           count(local).as("c").select(last,"x").
           map(unfold().as("m").select("w").sack(sum).
               select(last,"m").select("l").sack(div).
               select(last,"m").select("c").sack(div).sack().fold()).as("score").
           select(last, "score","x").by(sum(local)).by(tail(local, 1).select("v")).
           order().by(select("score"), decr).select("x").values("name")
==>c
==>e
==>d
==>b
```

The only good thing about this traversal is, that the `weight` properties don't have to have another data type - `int` works fine.

Comment: Wow! That's great. I was expecting it to be complicated but not THAT complicated. I doubt I would have ever reached a solution, so thank you very much.

Even though, when I run that in the gremlin console I keep getting a mysterious error that says:

"No such property: assign for class: groovysh_evaluate".

I'm sure it has to be related with my local configuration, but do you know by any chance what can it be related with? Other operators work properly, such as mult or sum.

Comment: Ah, I just found out. I'm using Titan 1.0 which depends on TinkerPop 3.0.1, but the assign operator was added in TinkerPop 3.1.0.

Comment: Sucks, that Titan is so far behind. Without `assign` `sack` is pretty useless. I'll try to rewrite the traversal later today. Don't expect it to become simpler :).

Comment: Don't worry, I'll try to compile the dev branch for Titan 1.1 and see if it works. I've already taken too much of your time!

Comment: See the update for a TP 3.0.1 version of the traversal.

Comment: The traversal for TP 3.0.x worked! I compiled Titan 1.1 (depends on TP 3.1.x) and tried to run the original query. This time it failed because DefaultGraphTraversal.project is not defined and I guess it is because project is only supported in TP 3.2.x. I'll just use Titan 1.0 with the second version. Again, thanks for everything.